# Trouble with rake. Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've 1 problem.
I work with project, which use rails 2.3 and ruby 1.8.7. My task - is update to rails 4.0.1.
But I need test this application before. This app doesn't have migrations therefore I using `rake db:schema:load` but when I start this command I see this error.

```
rake db:schema:load --trace
(in /home/alxgol/Projects/nucleus-core)
DEPRECATION WARNING: Rake tasks in vendor/plugins/find_conditions/tasks and vendor/plugins/ym4r_gm/tasks are deprecated. Use lib/tasks instead. (called from /home/alxgol/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/rails-2.3.11/lib/tasks/rails.rb:10)
** Invoke db:schema:load (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
rake aborted!
Mysql::Error: Table 'core_development.payments' doesn't exist: SHOW FIELDS FROM `payments`
```

I think that this problem appears because the information from table `payments` calls before thаn this table was created. But I dont find, where this call

**UPDATE**

```
/home/alxgol/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/activerecord-2.3.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:227:in `log'
/home/alxgol/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/activerecord-2.3.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:324:in `execute'
/home/alxgol/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/activerecord-2.3.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:471:in `columns'
/home/alxgol/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/activerecord-2.3.11/lib/active_record/base.rb:1305:in `columns'
/home/alxgol/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/activerecord-2.3.11/lib/active_record/base.rb:1318:in `column_names'
/home/alxgol/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/activerecord-2.3.11/lib/active_record/base.rb:1331:in `column_methods_hash'
/home/alxgol/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/activerecord-2.3.11/lib/active_record/base.rb:2025:in `all_attributes_exists?'
/home/alxgol/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/activesupport-2.3.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:406:in `all?'
/home/alxgol/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/activerecord-2.3.11/lib/active_record/base.rb:2025:in `each'
/home/alxgol/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/activerecord-2.3.11/lib/active_record/base.rb:2025:in `all?'
/home/alxgol/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/activerecord-2.3.11/lib/active_record/base.rb:2025:in `all_attributes_exists?'
/home/alxgol/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/activerecord-2.3.11/lib/active_record/base.rb:1876:in `method_missing_without_paginate'
/home/alxgol/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/will_paginate-2.3.12/lib/will_paginate/finder.rb:170:in `method_missing'
/home/alxgol/Projects/nucleus-core/config/initializers/site_config.rb:15
/home/alxgol/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/activesupport-2.3.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:171:in `load_without_new_constant_marking'
/home/alxgol/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/activesupport-2.3.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:171:in `load'
/home/alxgol/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/activesupport-2.3.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:547:in `new_constants_in'
/home/alxgol/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/activesupport-2.3.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:171:in `load'
/home/alxgol/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/rails-2.3.11/lib/initializer.rb:622:in `load_application_initializers'
/home/alxgol/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/rails-2.3.11/lib/initializer.rb:621:in `each'
/home/alxgol/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/rails-2.3.11/lib/initializer.rb:621:in `load_application_initializers'
/home/alxgol/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/rails-2.3.11/lib/initializer.rb:176:in `process'
/home/alxgol/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/rails-2.3.11/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `send'
/home/alxgol/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/rails-2.3.11/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
/home/alxgol/Projects/nucleus-core/config/environment.rb:14
/home/alxgol/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/activesupport-2.3.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `require'
/home/alxgol/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/activesupport-2.3.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `require'
/home/alxgol/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/activesupport-2.3.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:547:in `new_constants_in'
/home/alxgol/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/activesupport-2.3.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `require'
/home/alxgol/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/rails-2.3.11/lib/tasks/misc.rake:4
/home/alxgol/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `call'
/home/alxgol/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `execute'
/home/alxgol/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `each'
/home/alxgol/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `execute'
/home/alxgol/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:597:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/alxgol/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-head/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/home/alxgol/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:590:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/alxgol/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:607:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/home/alxgol/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:604:in `each'
/home/alxgol/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:604:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/home/alxgol/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:596:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/alxgol/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-head/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/home/alxgol/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:590:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/alxgol/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:583:in `invoke'
/home/alxgol/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2051:in `invoke_task'
/home/alxgol/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `top_level'
/home/alxgol/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `each'
/home/alxgol/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `top_level'
/home/alxgol/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/alxgol/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2023:in `top_level'
/home/alxgol/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2001:in `run'
/home/alxgol/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/alxgol/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1998:in `run'
/home/alxgol/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/rake-0.8.7/bin/rake:31
/home/alxgol/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/home/alxgol/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/bin/rake:23
/home/alxgol/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15
```

**SOLUTION**

If you look closely at the error you will see that it refers to a /home/alxgol/Projects/nucleus-core/config/initializers/site_config.rb:15. In this file was call from payments table. I commented out this, and after that rake db:schema:load perfectly worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look closely at the error you will see that it refers to a `/home/alxgol/Projects/nucleus-core/config/initializers/site_config.rb:15`. In this file was call from `payments` table. I commented out this, and after that `rake db:schema:load` perfectly worked.